# MPS canonical form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, spin-chains, tensor-network

If I express a MPS in its (left, right or anything else) canonical form, does this representation encode all Schmidt decompositions between a subsystem and its complement,rather than only the Schmidt decompositions between left and right?
And is it the same in open and periodic boundary counditions?

I am looking for conditions on the site tensors such that the Schmidt decomposition of the MPS with respect to any bipartition (not limited to left vs right, but also, say, 1 site in the bulk of the chain vs the rest of the system) is encoded within the tensors.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean "encode all Schmidt decompositions", as any MPS representation of a quantum state carries the full information about the state, and thus all of its Schmidt decompositions, but I suspect you are looking for Vidal's $\Gamma$-$\Lambda$-form (see Equation (6) of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0310089).

There, the (open boundary condition) MPS is written as an alternating sequence of tensors $\Gamma^{(s)}$ which carry a physical index, and diagonal tensors $\Lambda^{(s)}$ which connect $\Gamma^{(s)}$ and $\Gamma^{(s+1)}$. The tensors are chosen such that each $\Gamma$, together with the $\Lambda$ left (right) of it, is in left (right) canonical form. Then, $\Lambda^{(s)}$ carries precisely the entanglement spectrum at that cut.

On a technical level, one way to find this decomposition is to first bring the MPS into left canonical form, and then determine the transformation needed to bring it into right canonical form: From there, it is straightforward to obtain $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma$.

A method where this representation is commonly used is the TEBD algorithm, so it might make sense to look for references on that topic if you want to find more information on that.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! As a last comment, can one obtain from the canonical Vidal's form the Schmidt decomposition of the state corresponding to the bipartition between, e.g., one site in the bulk and all remaining sites? And would the Schmidt coefficients be all products of the ones stored in the $\Lambda$ matrices to its left and right?

Comment: Again, the question is *how* you can obtain this -- the information is there for sure. The point of this form is that you can obtain an orthonormal basis for the left and right end of the chain (which is what you need for the Schmidt decomposition); so if you are willing to do some operation which involves the central sites (and -- at least naively -- might be exponentially costly in the number of sites in the center) then this is possible.